# Why do my privileges not carry over to other Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, privileges, linked-accounts

I would like to know the reason behind my privileges not carrying over to other Stack Exchange accounts. I understand that reputation is an indication of how good you are at helping, etc, so it makes sense they wouldn't carry over. But when I use another Stack Exchange account, I would expect my privileges would remain, since in at least one account I have proven that I am an individual that will not abuse the system (e.g. allow me to create tags or edit a question - Stack Exchange deems me worthy of that in one account, but not another).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Each site in the network is different; Just because you are 'trusted' to a certain degree on Stack Overflow does not mean you should also be trusted as much on, say, Cooking. They have different standards of posting, editing, and the like. And just because you know about programming does not mean you know anything about cooking.

There is a very small association bonus, which you have achieved already. This is to get you past some of the most basic abilities. But the higher-up stuff needs you to know what you are doing on that *specific* site.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. Although something like creating my own tag in gaming would've been something I'd expect to do be able to do from the beginning since I see that as a system understanding. The restriction makes sense though. Thanks

Comment: @TheoScholiadis I think I see what you mean, but I disagree about tags; I wouldn't expect to go to any other SE site and have any idea what tags are good or bad to create. I would expect each site has different standards there.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanx again

Answer (score 8):

You do carry some of the basic privileges once you gain 200 reputation in one site. This leads to automatic 100 rep bonus on **any other site you join** as your accounted will be linked.

To me, it sounds just fair enough.

100 rep gives you 10 privileges:

- Participate in per-site meta (5 rep)
- Remove new user restrictions (10 rep)
- Create community-wiki posts (10 rep)
- Vote up questions and answers (15 rep)
- Flag posts (15 rep)
- Talk in chat (20 rep)
- Comment everywhere (50 rep)
- Set a bounty on a question (75 rep)
- Edit community wiki questions (100 rep)
- Create chat rooms (100 rep)

Answer (score 3):

> I understand that reputation is an indication of how good you are at helping, etc, so it makes sense they wouldn't carry over.

You got that right here. You could for example be good at photography and have a deep understanding of how the community on [photography.stackexchange.com](http://photography.stackexchange.com) works and of its standards and ways. You could be a very experienced and active user there and thus have a high rep giving you a bunch of privileges.

Now you could be joining [physics.stackexchange.com](http://physics.stackexchange.com). You will receive a bonus of 100 rep there to remove the new user restrictions, because you very well know how the system works, but that doesn't imply that you know how the community over there works. Thus, privileges are not transferred from one SE account to another.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. Although there are some other things I'd expect to be able to do from the beginning, but that's another topic :P Thanks